# What is wrong with the logic of following code?

Tags: java

The following code gives only two outputs (2 and 3), after this it gets terminated, why doesn't it continue?

```
public class PrimeSeries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        boolean prime = true;
        
        for(int i=2;i<=N;i++) {
            for(int j=2;j*j<=i;j++) {
                if(i%j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(prime == true) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you input as N?

Comment: You need to reset `isPrime` to `true` _inside_ the outer loop, right before starting the inner loop.

Comment: Look at your `i=2` if you input `4` it will give you 3 outputs, the bigger the number of `N` the more output you can get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't work because you never made the variable **boolean prime true again**
So just make the **boolean** back to **true** again after every iteration of the inner for loop.

```
   public class PrimeSeries {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int N = sc.nextInt();
            boolean prime = true;
            
            for(int i=2;i<=N;i++) {

               // ADD THIS LINE
               prime = true;

                for(int j=2;j*j<=i;j++) {
                    if(i%j == 0) {
                        prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(prime == true) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

That is it!